# Не могу клонировать код JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть код только для одного div.
Мне нужно эту функцию применить к другим дивам с разными id.

Меняю параметры в функции и ничего не получается, работает только один из них или вообще не один. что делать

```
var price1;
var reloadData = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd', function(data){
    var float1 = parseFloat(data.ticker.price).toFixed(2)
    if(price1 && price1 > float) {
        $('#result1').html('<font color="red">' + float1 + '</font>')
    }
    else if(price1 && price1 < float1) {
        $('#result1').html('<font color="green">' + float1 + '</font>')
    }
    else {
        $('#result1').text(float1)
    }
    price1 = float1
  })
}

setInterval('reloadData()', 5000)
$(document).ready(reloadData)

var price2;
var reloadData = function() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd', function(data){
    var float2 = parseFloat(data.ticker.price).toFixed(2)
    if(price2 && price2 > float2) {
        $('#result2').html('<font color="red">' + float2 + '</font>')
    }
    else if(price2 && price2 < float) {
        $('#result2').html('<font color="green">' + float2 + '</font>')
    }
    else {
        $('#result2').text(float2)
    }
    price2 = float2
  })
}

setInterval('reloadData()', 5000)
$(document).ready(reloadData)
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">Loading...</div>
<div id="result2">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем что-то клонировать ? сделайте одну функцию, для всех.

Как-то так :

```js
function reloadAll() {
  setInterval(function() {
    reloadData('result1', 'url 1');
  }, 1000);
  setInterval(function() {
    reloadData('result2', 'url 2');
  }, 1000);
};

function reloadData(id, url) {
  // url - для разных дивов разные url  
  var float = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var prev = parseFloat($('#' + id).text());

  var color = float >= prev ? 'green' : 'red';
  $('#' + id).text(float).css('color', color);
};

$(document).ready(reloadAll);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">Loading...</div>
<div id="result2">Loading...</div>
```

ПС: **никогда** не делайте много функций, которые делают одно и то же, лучше сделать 1ну, но более гибкую, функцию.

Comment: Так у него разные api, как я понял. Первый раз `https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd`, а второй `https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd` Или можно сделать Ваш пример для двух разных?

Comment: я даже `url` в функу передал...

Comment: Простите, не заметил.

Comment: Ничего страшно, все мы ошибаемся)) всёравно спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

```js
let base = [
  { id: 1, url: 'btc-usd' },
  { id: 2, url: 'ltc-usd' }
];

setInterval(reloadData, 5000)
$(document).ready(reloadData)

function reloadData() {
  for(let i = 0; i < base.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON(`https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/${base[i].url}`, function(data){
      const $result = $(`#result${base[i].id}`),
        newPrice = parseFloat(data.ticker.price).toFixed(2);
      
      if(base[i].price && base[i].price !== newPrice) {
        $result.html(`<font color="${(base[i].price > newPrice ? 'red' : 'green')}">${newPrice}</font>`);
      } else {
        $result.text(newPrice)
      }
      
      base[i].price = newPrice;
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">Loading...</div>
<div id="result2">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте назвать вторую функцию не `reloadData`, а `reloadData2` или более понятным названием. А затем `$(document).ready(reloadData2)`

Comment: не получается ((

Comment: @Encode_VI А `setInterval('reloadData()', 5000)` Тоже поменяли на `reloadData2()` ?